# How to execute php file into variable?

Tags: php

Does it possible to execute php file and store its output into some variable?

For example i have one global template, then i need to process subtemplates, and afterall i need to insert that subtemplate output into global template block.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [output control functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), buffer the output with [`ob_start`](http://docs.php.net/ob_start) and retrieve it with [`ob_get_contents`](http://docs.php.net/ob_get_contents):

```
ob_start();
func();
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: thank, this is all i need. i just forgot about that buffers feature.